# Given integers C and N, (c <= n <= 10^9), find the amount of pairs i,j (n >= i >= j >= 1), where gcd(i,j) == C

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, timeout, greatest-common-divisor

Given integers C and N, (c <= n <= 10^9), find the amount of pairs i,j (n >= i >= j >= 1), where gcd(i,j) == C

```
long long gcd(long long int a, long long int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}

void solve(int tt){
    int c,n;
    cin >> c >> n;
    ll ans = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for(int j = i; j <= n; j++){
            if(gcd(i,j) == c) ans++;
        }
    }
    cout << ans;
    return;
}
```

This is getting timed out and I've tried various different ways to try and fix it - nothing is working... Does anyone know the code to optimize this? (Output %100000007)

Comment: Usually, a **T**ime **L**imit **E**xceeded error (TLE) means you need a faster algorithm.  Code sites like this often are looking for bizarre fast algorithms, that not commonly seen in the real world.

Comment: Please post the results, in text, of your debugging session.  Specify the inputs you used to create the issue.

Comment: I'm confused.  Does your definition of `gcd` mean 1) Greatest Common Divisor; or 2) Grand-Central-Dispatch?  You have tagged "grand-central-dispatch" and I can't figure out how it relates to your code (as you code doesn't dispatch).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews :-D

Comment: It means "Greatest Common Divisor". my code kept getting a TLE. I dont know why it tagged "Grand-Central Dispatch".

Comment: You can improve your code by checking `if (c % i == 0)` before the `j` loop, because `c` cannot be the gcd of `i`, when `c` isn't a multiple of `i`. For example, when `c` is `100000001`, you do not need to run the `j` loop for any even number in `i`.

Comment: "Output %100000007" OK so already you know (or at least, it's a very strong hint) that you cannot count one by one. If you could count one by one, the result would not be so big that the problem required the result to be given modulo some number. So they fact that they specified that, almost certainly means that the "raw" count is some some *big* number, at least for *some* inputs.

Answer (score 1):

"Given integers C and N, (c <= n <= 10^9), find the amount of pairs i,j (n >= i >= j >= 1), where gcd(i,j) == C"

We can divide everything by C to get:

How many integers i and j satisfy: 2 <= j < i <= n/c, and are relatively prime?

Let's check a few:

```
n/c   count (new pairs listed in parens)
<=2   0
3     1  (2,3) 
4     2  (3,4)
5     5  (2,5), (3,5), (4,5)
6     6  (5,6)
7     11 (2,7), (3,7), (4,7), (5,7), (6,7)
8     14 (3,8), (5,8), (7,8)
9     19 (2,9), (4,9), (5,9), (7,9), (8,9)
```

Each time we increment i, we can pair it with all smaller values of j >= 2 that don't have any of the same factors. For primes this is all smaller values of j >= 2.

This is https://oeis.org/A015613.

Here's an approach courtesy of [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eulers-totient-function/):

Find the count of smaller integers >= 2 relatively prime to n, also known as Euler's totient function, in O(sqrt(n) * log(n)) time as follows:

```
1) Initialize result as n
2) Consider every number 'p' (where 'p' varies from 2 to Φn). 
   If p divides n, then do following
   a) Subtract all multiples of p from 1 to n [all multiples of p
      will have gcd more than 1 (at least p) with n]
   b) Update n by repeatedly dividing it by p.
3) If the reduced n is more than 1, then remove all multiples
   of n from result.
```

Add these up for 2 through n in O((n^1.5) * log(n)) time.